# Android Studio could not detect appt even though it is located at position specified by error

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, aapt

I updated Android Studio and the SDK Manager and it worked fine until it said:

Gradle: Execution failed for task ':MyListViewProject:processDebugResources'. > Running C:\Users\HP-Pavilion\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.2.2\aapt.exe failed. See output

The thing is that aapt is at the location specified in the error and is not missing,I was able to run aapt by clicking on the exe file.

How can I solve this problem?

I am running a 32 bit version of Windows 7. 
Thanks in advance for any suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found that this problem only occures if the name of the layout xml file contains capital letter.
This counts for all Files (also drawables etc.) in "res" Folder

So in your project under src/main/res/layout/ directory you have the layout xml file, make sure its name doesn't contain capital letter.

My setup is:
Windows 7 x64
Android Studio AI 130.709792

Comment: Thank You!  I am very new to Android development and decided to learn with Studio.  That was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on Ubuntu trying to use a mp3 (in res/raw) with '-' in the name; I'm not sure if this is something I should have been aware of but changing the '-' to '_' fixed the compilation error.